# How to run GWT in production mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am trying to run GWT project in production mode, as per the instructions at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse. So my project `foo` is located as a folder `foo` in my desktop under th `workspace` folder. When I right click on the `foo` project in the Project Explorer, click `Google` - `GWT Compile`, I see some message like `permutations 1, 2..` etc in the debugging console, after which it says that compilation is complete.

However, contrary to what the Google page says, no additional `HTML`/`Javascript` files are generated in the `war` folder. Also, if I enter `foo/war/foo.html` in the URL bar, I am getting a timed-out error (even though the page contains only a simple `alert` call).

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: `foo.html` is supposed to contain some boilerplate code to inject the web-app's javascript (`<script src="..*.nocache.js></script>`). does it?

Comment: No idea...That is possible.

Comment: well, i'd suggest than you read on the basics on the GWT docs.

Comment: I know the basics very well. And I have read the docs as well, that's why I pointed to it in the URL. The problem is there even after this, that's why I am asking...

Comment: can u paste the stacktrace

Comment: no it will generate chache.js  if you compiled successfully ..

Comment: Then how do I load the HTML file in the browser? Do i have to give the complete filepath?

Comment: Please stop down voting....almost evey gwt starter will face this...

Comment: How you are running the app?

Comment: Previously, I was clicking `Run - Run As - Web Application`, then double clicking the URL shown in the console window..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23799/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-cupidvogel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running in GWT development mode  after the compile

remove the parameter  `gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`   in the url given by eclipse

After you compile the code the whole gwt code will convert in to `javascript` so you can access like an normal  `HTML` page with proper paths .

Comment: @suresh since gwt 2.8.0 beta this doesn't work. Popup says "the gwt module may need to be compiled". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your GWT project is a Maven project, and you are using [gwt-maven-plugin](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgwt-maven-plugin.github.io%2Fgwt-maven-plugin%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFcLvRKhHXfok69_xHkdi98EFPjGg), you can run [*mvn jetty:run-war*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271134/1357094) (for example, using that as the goal of an Eclipse Maven Run Configuration):  That will GWT compile your project into a war, and run it on localhost, thus running your Prod mode.

Answer (score 0):

*This can test ui-only features in Production Mode.*  That's useful if that's all you need to do, especially if otherwise the running of a server for Production Mode occupies limited resources of your development machine that you'd like to save (whereas occupying them with a running server would be a "waste" if your testing doesn't need to make requests to that server anyways).

If your GWT project...

1. doesn't make any server requests for data yet (maybe your project is still in its infancy as well), and...
2. is a Maven project

... you can...

1. GWT compile your project
2. [Maven package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422142/missing-the-maven-package-menu-entry-in-eclipse/15722549#15722549) (those directions use [gwt-Eclipse-maven-plugin](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgwt-maven-plugin.github.io%2Fgwt-maven-plugin%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFcLvRKhHXfok69_xHkdi98EFPjGg)) your project
3. open the packaged GWT host page (i.e: index.html, or < Your Module >.html, under yourProject/target/yourProject-< snapshot version >/) in a browser.  Profit!

This is sufficient to test the project's ui-only features, thus in Production Mode.  In fact, if your project has features that make server requests for data, but you aren't testing any of them, then this will still work to test just those ui-only features. Basically, any features requesting server data will not have those requests returned (as there is no server running to do that), but all other features will function, as they are ui-only.

If you need to test features that make server requests for data, then you'll have to run Production Mode via a server (that would respond to the requests).  For example with Jetty server, see my [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34526849/1357094) here.