# No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have added jetty mvn plugin code in my project pom.xml.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.26</version>
  <configuration>
    <contextPath>/redkites</contextPath>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>start-jetty</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <daemon>true</daemon>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I use commands `sudo mvn compile` and `sudo mvn clean install`, I didn't find any errors & build successfully, but when I type the command `sudo mvn jetty:run`, I'm getting an error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Please suggest a way to solve it. Thank you

Comment: Try run all the `mvn` commands without sudo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Maven Plugin Jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426557/missing-maven-plugin-jetty)

Answer (score 42):

You may need to add `org.eclipse.jetty` to the list of `groupId`s looked up by default.

So edit your `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` accordingly:

```
<pluginGroups>
  <!-- your existing plugin groups if any -->
  ...
  <pluginGroup>org.eclipse.jetty</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Quoting the `Shortening the Command Line` section of the [plugin development guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html),

> ... add your plugin's groupId to the list of groupIds searched by
>   default. To do this, you need to add the following to your
>   ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml file:
>
> ```
> <pluginGroups>
>   <pluginGroup>sample.plugin</pluginGroup>
> </pluginGroups>
> ```

---

Look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) for more about what `groupId`s are looked up default:

> By default, Maven will search the groupId **org.apache.maven.plugins** for
>   prefix-to-artifactId mappings for the plugins it needs to perform a
>   given build.
>
> ...
>
> Maven will always search the following groupId's
>   **after** searching any plugin groups specified in the user's settings:
>
> - org.apache.maven.plugins
> - org.codehaus.mojo

Answer (score 27):

if you don't find the settings.xml file in your home directory

then add the default settings.xml file

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
  <offline>false</offline>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.eclipse.jetty</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what worked for me in a multimodule Maven project in Eclipse:

1 Open Run Configurations dialog.

2.Look at the “Base Directory:”  Is there really the directory of your **webapp’s submodule** or is it the **parent module**’s directory?

3 If it is the latter, click on “Workspace” button and select the submodule’s (webapp’s) directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was running the command in the directory in which the project was present but the command worked fine after switching to the one directory up i.e in one in which all the files of the project were present.

Answer (score 0):

Please Note:

If you are running your app using the command bellow:

> mvn spring-boot:run

Make sure you are in the directory that contains the pom.xml file. Otherwise, you will run into the No plugin found for prefix 'project-name' in the current project and in the plugin groups error.